# How to write class object to bin file

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, outputstream, serializable

I am using Java to map some huge graph. I have a personalized class object that has this map, it is formed of several hashmaps and calls other personalized classes which are also made out of various objects.

My problem is that every time I run this to make tests, it takes around 5 minutes to map everything and then for each node it can take from 1 to 10 minutes to do some calculations. And every time I have to fix something on the code, I have to go through that waiting time.

So my question(s)

Is there is any way to store the main object class (which is composed of several primitive and non-primitive objects) as a binary file that I can save once and the read from then on?

How would the parsing happen?

I've started looking into the FileOutputStream/ObjectOutputStream and FileInputStream/ObjectInputStream, but I am not sure I understood correctly if they are good options for this situation.

Any comments and advice will be most appreciated.

I attach the code that I tried to use to save the class object.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("tbox.dat");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(tboxObject);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

That's for the first run, after that I swapped the code for:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("tbox.dat");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
tboxObject savedTboxObject = (tboxObject) ois.readObject();
```

I will add that these are objects made out not only of ints and string, but of hashmaps, lists, and arrays of other also complex objects.

Comment: hmm, code looks fine. hard to say what the problem could be. are you swallowing any exceptions in a catch block?

Answer (score 0):

From the [java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(yourObject);
    oos.close();
```

Just make sure all objects in the graph implement serializable.

Comment: hi, I have tried this way. I implemented serializable in all the object that are present on "MyObject" class and then I try to read it with. `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myFile.dat"); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis); MyObject mo = (MyObject) ois.readObject();` This causes a EOF exception. As a side note, the file saved was 1kb size, I ws expecting sth of at least 4 or 5 mb. It is a lot of info.

Comment: Must be something wrong with your object graph, without some code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can serialize and save the objects using the OutputStream/InputStream classes. However do watch out when you modify the class (add/delete/modify an instance variable for example) and then try to read a previously saved file.

Comment: hi aldrin, the file would only be read on the 1st run. after that everytime is modified i should be saved so then the program stops and starts again it has the updated version

Comment: in that case, saving it in a file should be good enough. post your code in case you can't get it to work.

Comment: @joel_gil: Your code looks right. Do you have any problems with it?

Comment: @paulo: the problem is that after the first run the file i get is 1kb size, when I wouldnt expect anything under the range of megabytes. And so when I try to read it I get an EOF exception =S

Comment: @joel_gil: Have you got try..catch around your code that is ignoring the exceptions? Can you print out any exception caught?

Answer (score -1):

[Serialize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is probably what you want. Implement the serialiable interface in your class then use ObjectOutputStream to write the object to file.

Comment: I suppose you mean `Serializable`?